# SQL - Identify Customer Line of Business by their Product Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, netezza

I have a table that contains customer information -their customer number, product, etc.. I want to determine what line of business each customer is a member of based on what products they own. Each customer can have 1 or more rows (each row signifies a customer and their product). It looks something like this:

```
Customer #  Product
-----------------------------------------   
000000001   BROKERAGE   
000000001   CHECKING
000000001   CREDIT CARD 
000000001   SAVING
000000001   LIFE INSURANCE
```

Now, this is just one customer, but I have rules as to which products are part of which lines of business, such as:

BANK: CHECKING, CREDIT CARD, SAVINGS

INVESTMENTS: BROKERAGE, MUTUAL FUND

LIFE INSURANCE: LIFE INSURANCE

What I want to do it look at the whole table, by customer and say, if this customer owns any banking product, I want to create a new column "Bank" and put a "Y" in that column for every row that customer has in the tale - this would tell me that, no matter what row I am looking at, that customer was a bank customer. In the end, I'd like a column for all of these LOBs, so the end product would look like this:

```
Customer #  Product          Bank    Investments    Life
---------------------------------------------------------
000000002   BROKERAGE          Y          Y           N
000000002   CHECKING           Y          Y           N
000000002   CREDIT CARD        Y          Y           N
000000002   SAVING             Y          Y           N
```

The logic here is that the Bank and Investment columns have "Y" because the customer has at least one product from each of those LOBs. However, the customer does not have a life insurance policy, so that whole column for that customer would be "N".

I have multiple customer, obviously, so I was trying to do this with a case statement, but the one I used is only looks at the column for the current row, so I only get "Y" where that one row matches. I want any row for that customer that matches... I thought maybe doing something with a PARTITION or GROUP BY, but I have no idea where to start.... Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the two solutions above were helpful, in the end the solution I was looking for was much more simple. I found a post that described a similar issue and the suggested solution was to use MAX() over that column, grouped by the ID/user/whatever. So, if I have the following:

```
Customer #  Product
----------------------------   
000000001   BROKERAGE   
000000001   CHECKING
000000001   CREDIT CARD 
000000001   SAVING
000000001   LIFE INSURANCE 
000000002   BROKERAGE   
000000002   LIFE INSURANCE
```

I create the appropriate columns for Bank, Investments and Life using CASE statements to result in the following:

```
Customer #  Product          Bank    Investments    Life
---------------------------------------------------------
000000001   BROKERAGE          N          Y           N
000000001   CHECKING           Y          N           N
000000001   CREDIT CARD        Y          N           N
000000001   SAVING             Y          N           N
000000002   BROKERAGE          N          Y           N
000000002   LIFE INSURANCE     N          N           Y
```

So, now I know based on what rows, what LOB that product is part of, but since I just want a summary of what LOBs each customer belongs to (Y/N). In this case, I know customer #1 is part of Bank and Investments (that customer owns at least one product from Bank and Investments). Customer #2 only has Investments and Life Insurance, but no banking products. Therefore, I want to see:

```
Customer #  Bank    Investments    Life
---------------------------------------------------------
000000001     Y          Y           N
000000002     N          Y           Y
```

I do this by doing another SELECT from the prior table/result grouped by Customer #, doing a MAX over each of those Y/N columns as needed:

```
SELECT CUST_NUMBER,
MAX(BANK) AS BANK,
MAX(INVENTMENTS) AS INVESTMENTS,
MAX(LIFE) as LIFE
FROM
( ORIGINAL QUERY TO GET PRIOR TABLE
  GROUP BY CUST_NUMBER
) A
ON CUST_NUMBER = A.CUST_NUMBER
```

This gives you a Y if it exists for each column for any rows related to that customer number. If it's all "Y", you get a "Y", if there is at least 1 "Y", you get a "Y". If the column for that customer is a "N" for all values in that column, you get a "N". I tested this on several scenarios and it works great. I hope this help someone else who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT tbl.customer, tbl.product,
case when temp.Bank>0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Bank,
case when temp.Investment>0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Investment,
case when temp.Insurance>0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Insurance
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT customer,
sum(case when Product in ('CHECKING', 'CREDIT CARD', 'SAVINGS') then 1 else 0 end) as Bank, 
sum(case when Product in ('BROKERAGE','MUTUAL FUNDS') then 1 else 0 end) as Investment,
sum(case when Product in ('LIFE INSURANCE') then 1 else 0 end) as Insurance
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Customer) tmp
on tmp.customer=tbl.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it... quick, simple, and fast solution.

```
DECLARE @Products table
(
        CustomerNumber int
    ,   Product nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'BROKERAGE')
INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'CHECKI[NG')
INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'CREDIT CARD')
INSERT @Products VALUES (2, 'SAVINGS')
INSERT @Products VALUES (2, 'LIFE INSURANCE')


;WITH
ProductTypes AS
(
    SELECT
            CustomerNumber
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('CHECKING', 'CREDIT CARD', 'SAVINGS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bank
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('BROKERAGE', 'MUTUAL FUND') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Investments
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('LIFE INSURANCE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Life
    FROM    @Products
    GROUP BY CustomerNumber
)
SELECT
        Products.CustomerNumber
    ,   Products.Product
    ,   CASE WHEN Bank > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Bank
    ,   CASE WHEN Investments > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Investments
    ,   CASE WHEN Life > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Life
FROM    @Products AS Products
LEFT JOIN ProductTypes ON (ProductTypes.CustomerNumber = Products.CustomerNumber)
```

This version has been modified to take into account your comment that you're doing an initial join to get the source table.

```
DECLARE @Customer table
(
        CustomerNumber int
)

INSERT @Customer VALUES (1)
INSERT @Customer VALUES (2)

DECLARE @Products table
(
        CustomerNumber int
    ,   Product nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'BROKERAGE')
INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'CHECKI[NG')
INSERT @Products VALUES (1, 'CREDIT CARD')
INSERT @Products VALUES (2, 'SAVINGS')
INSERT @Products VALUES (2, 'LIFE INSURANCE')


;WITH
CustomerProducts AS
(
    SELECT
            Customer.CustomerNumber
        ,   Products.Product
    FROM @Customer AS Customer
    LEFT JOIN @Products AS Products ON (Products.CustomerNumber = Customer.CustomerNumber)
)
, ProductTypes AS
(
    SELECT
            CustomerNumber
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('CHECKING', 'CREDIT CARD', 'SAVINGS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bank
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('BROKERAGE', 'MUTUAL FUND') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Investments
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('LIFE INSURANCE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Life
    FROM    CustomerProducts
    GROUP BY CustomerNumber
)
SELECT
        CustomerProducts.CustomerNumber
    ,   CustomerProducts.Product
    ,   CASE WHEN Bank > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Bank
    ,   CASE WHEN Investments > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Investments
    ,   CASE WHEN Life > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Life
FROM    CustomerProducts
LEFT JOIN ProductTypes ON (ProductTypes.CustomerNumber = CustomerProducts.CustomerNumber)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the answer is not right. Here is my test case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31e19eff150f19cde09931e8ff386dcf

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the question and have I've updated my solution accordingly

Comment: @ Gen Wan Yeah, both answers give me what a single set of case statements give me. I only get Y and N in the new columns specific to that row - I'm looking for Y and N based on everything in that Product column for each customer.

Comment: @EmilySamanthaHeiner That works for the test case that  posted. Now I just need to figure out how to integrate it. The initial data set comes from a join among three tables, so I need to work with it to integrate...

Comment: You can put another CTE in before ProductTypes to do the initial join on the three tables, then reference it instead of the table variable in the example. If this is useful, please consider marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that initial CTE to join some tables together first